# DIY table saw installation

Tags: table-saw, workbench, router-table

I am resurfacing my workbench with 25mm hardwood ply. I am inverting an up/down router and tablesaw into it (between tracks).
I want to use thinner insert plates (for the zero clearence saw and so that both tools can raise and lower)
What material for the inserts should I use?
I want a max. of 10mm thick, prob. about 150 x 150mm and 100 x 150mm.
Would MDF be smooth and strong enough, some sort of formica faced material ... alternative suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. If you've seen enough out there to know what a zero-clearance is and that they can be made by the user themselves then you'll have seen examples of what they can be made from, or even are typically made from..... If your application is slightly different to the typical ZCI however then you might need to describe it in more detail, or provide a quick sketch or two (with a photo of your saw if that would help), to give a better idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Graphus; I'll add some more detail later; what is ZCI?

Comment: Ahhh!!! ... Zero Clearence Insert?

Comment: The example I was looking at was this one .... but I couldnt identify the material used for the inserts?  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=skMNEDn52Ys&feature=youtu.be

Comment: After a bit more looking, I think some laminate flooring should do the trick. I'll hunt around for a pack that is thin/strong/smooth enough then inset flush to the workbench with countersunk machinehead screws & nuts (for easy removal). I'll post some pictures when done.

Comment: I've just purchased my first table saw (in ages), and one of my first projects is figuring out how to make some ZCIs for it. I'm simply using some leftover sanded plywood for them. In some initial test cuts (in more of the same leftover sanded plywood), I've really had no issues with smooth enough. Thick enough is really my issue as the ply is barely thicker than the deck of the saw, and I want to be able to put a catch at the back to help hold it down. I'll switch to some old-growth framing lumber that I pulled out of the house during a renovation project...